# simple adapter cant update database

Tags: java, android, database, android-sqlite, simpleadapter

Hey guys i have made a listview of data from my database using simple adapter but i dont know how to update it everytime the database changes.Any help?The notifyDataSetChanged(); method doesnt work and i cant find out what to do.

**MainActivity**

> ```
>       @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_general_discussion);
>     db = new SQLiteHandler(this);
>
>     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> emaillist = db.getMessage();
>     if (emaillist.size() != 0) {
>          ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, emaillist,
>                 R.layout.raw_layout,
>                 new String[]{"user_posted", "post", "posted_at", "post_id"}, new int[]{
>                 R.id.text_user_name, R.id.text_user_post, R.id.text_user_date, R.id.text_user_number});
>         setListAdapter(adapter);
>
>     }
> ```

**HelperClass**

> ```
>     public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getMessage(){
>     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> message = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
>     String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_POSTING;
>
>     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
>     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
>
>     if ( cursor.moveToFirst()) {
>         do {
>             HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
>             map.put("post_id", cursor.getString(0));
>             map.put("user_posted", cursor.getString(1));
>             map.put("post", cursor.getString(2));
>             map.put("posted_at", cursor.getString(3));
>             message.add(map);
>         } while (cursor.moveToNext());
>     }
>
>     return message;
> }
> ```

Comment: could you please add update function to check whats wrong

Comment: Where do you call `notifyDataSetChanged` and do you call it on the main thread (which is the ui thread)?

Comment: hey i add it in posting button click event so every time i press the button the list is updated

Comment: btnposting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String post = inputPost.getText().toString().trim();
                String user_posted = txtName.getText().toString().trim();



                if (!post.isEmpty()) {
                    postThreads(post, user_posted);


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

Declare your adapter & list global level

```
class example{
ListAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> emaillist;

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_general_discussion);
    db = new SQLiteHandler(this);

    emaillist = db.getMessage();
    if (emaillist.size() != 0) {
         adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, emaillist,
                R.layout.raw_layout,
                new String[]{"user_posted", "post", "posted_at", "post_id"}, new int[]{
                R.id.text_user_name, R.id.text_user_post, R.id.text_user_date, R.id.text_user_number});
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

When you want to update just

```
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: That is right. However, this is not a global level, this is on instance level.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your adapter as Public and just call
**`adapter.notifyDatasetChange();`**
when ever wherever you want to. This would update.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is a direct way to check if something changed in database
but you can make an action like Refresh.

make your adapter as global, when the action is triggered fill the adapter again and write `adapter.notifyDatasetChange();`

another way is to use `Thread`, put it into inner class of type `AsyncTask` 
then refill the array every minute 
then write `adapter.notifyDatasetChange();` after every check like this

```
doInBackground(){
while(true){
    checkDataBase();
refillAdapter();
adapter.notifyDatasetChange();

    Thread.sleep(1000*60);// sec * 60 sec =1min
} 
}
```

look at this link how to use AsyncTask class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html